# jaxws and camel route within servicemix

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I would like to do something like this:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="AbcEsbHTTPEndpoint" 
    implementor="com.abc.esb.ABCWSServiceImpl"
    address="/ABCWSServiceService"
    wsdlLocation="wsdl/ABCWSService.wsdl"
    endpointName="e:ABCWSService"
    serviceName="s:ABCWSServiceService"
    xmlns:e="http://com.abc.esb/abcesb/services/ABCWSService"
    xmlns:s="http://com.abc.esb/abcesb/services/ABCWSService">
</jaxws:endpoint>


<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean://ABCWSServiceService"/>
        <to uri="cxf:bean:decodeClient"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>    

<jaxws:client id="decodeClient" 
    address="http://ESB-DEV1:9081/abcesb/services/Decoder"
    wsdlLocation="http://ESB-DEV1:9081/abcesb/services/Decoder?wsdl" 
    serviceClass="com.abc.esb.ABCServiceInterface" 
    abstract="true" > 
</jaxws:client>
```

I don't understand how to configure the camel route from the **`<jaxws:endpoint`>** to the **`<jaxws:client`>**  What is the syntax to use??  I know you can use **`<cxf:cxfEndpoint`>** but I don't want to use that if I don't have to.

I know how to do this with JBI, but I'm wanting to deploy this into servicemix using a OSGI bundle, not JBI.

Answer (score 2):

The `jaxws:client` you have in your configuration *is* an endpoint as is the `jaxws:endpoint` and could be connected using the [bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html) component:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="bean:AbcEsbHTTPEndpoint"/>
        <to uri="bean:decodeClient"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Usually there's a need to do something in between - say to adapt the message in some way - but the above will achieve the routing at least.

Answer (score -4):

See some of the cxf examples from the examples in the camel distribution. They show how to setup cxf, not as jbi.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yeah, I've looked through those quite a bit.  I think the example (camel-example-cxf-proxy) is exact use case.  Based on this example I can use a camel route from a "cxf:cxfEndpoint" configured end point.  I was curious if I could use a camel route to from a "jaxws:endpoint" end point.  I didn't know the syntax in the camel route to reference the jaxws:endpoint.  
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Guido, i am also try to install camel-example-cxf-proxy into serviceMix 4.3.0. The installation is fine (install -s wrap:file:/c:/...jar). But it looks like the example doesn't work. I am not able to access the WSDL when using SOAPUI to test. Could you please let me know how to make it work in ServiceMix

Comment: Claus ... I know you are brilliant because you invented Camel. But can we see some actual code? I've been searching for an actual example of routing to/from a jax-ws endpoint but cannot find one. You being the primary creator of Camel would be the BEST person to give an example (or even a link, something?). I will remove my downvote of this answer if you post an example. Cheers.